# Azure active directory authentication library (ADAL) logout not working

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, adal

I used my Azure Active Directory and I use the ADAL library to get the token and call the api with that token. The code I used to get the token is shown below:

```cs
var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/something.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=www.google.com";

AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(APIsConstant.authorityForDomain2);
AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(APIsConstant.graphResourceUriForDomain2, APIsConstant.clientIdForDomain2, new Uri("www.google.com"),string.Empty,string.Empty);
string accessToken = ar.AccessToken;

ac.TokenCache.Clear();

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue. What is something.onmicrosoft.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't including the access token in the request. You can do that by adding an Authorization header to the request before sending it.

```cs
// ... code to get authentication result ...

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
// Add an Authorization header using your authentication result (ar)
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", ar.CreateAuthorizationHeader());
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Note that you don't need to store the authentication result's access token in a variable. You can directly use its [`CreateAuthorizationHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.authenticationresult.createauthorizationheader?view=azure-dotnet) method which will include the token.

You may also need to change where you call `ac.TokenCache.Clear();`. As you have it now it will likely remove the just created token and the request will still fail even with the authorization header. You could move the call up to before you get the authentication result or down to after you make the API request. Or consider removing the call altogether.